# Taking remote control of a PC

Tags: remote, remote-access, remote-control

I'm a computer technician, I repair computer for my customers, and many of them don't pay in time. So instead of holding their computers with me until they pay what they have to. I want to give them their computers back and give the ability to pay later, and of course with a deadline.

So, is there a way to install some clean and safe piece of software on the customer's computer that I can use remotely to remind them for payment, or lock the computer if they are not willing to pay.

I know this is maybe strange and evil but I'm really losing lots of my money this way. But remember this will never be misused. Any suggestion please?

THanks.

Comment: What you are suggesting is illegal in many countries.

Comment: Can't you charge them upfront?

Comment: many people aren't willing to pay later, so how will they pay upfront

Comment: If they can't pay now, and can't pay later they shouldn't be customers, it's not worth it.  You would essentially be installing malware on their computer.

Answer (score 2):

Preventing access to someone else's computer is illegal.  Microsoft tried this and lost a major lawsuit.    The reason is, just because *you* say/think they didnt pay/activate/whatever doesnt make it true.  Perhaps they did pay and you forgot to process the payment, lost the check, etc.  If you were to lock someone out of their computer and they had made a payment, you could be liable for their lost income (if it was a business computer), or worse.

As for a reminder, an email should be sufficient.  Installing applications on peoples computers is just not the right way to go.  If they dont pay, you can always threaten to send them to a collections agency.

You should consult with a lawyer in your jurisdiction for all your *legal* options.

Comment: the problem is that it's not the case to take a lawsuit as it will cost me ~10 time the money I want to get paid for.

Comment: https://www.rocketlawyer.com/article/five-tips-for-hiring-a-debt-recovery-or-debt-collection-agency.rl